# How do I get behavior packs on Minecraft PE 0.16.0?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to get behavior packs on minecraft PE 0.16.0. I have tried everything I could of, but it still showed up with the normal minecraft PE pack.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Try to add some more context to your question, what sort of thing have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

If it is one of the .mcworld files, all you have to do is open it and then it will load in the world with the behaviour packs and resource packs built in.

Unfortunately the current version of Minecraft Pocket Edition (0.16.0) doesn't yet seem to be compatible with the packs by themselves - I've tried copying the folders from the world created by a .mcworld file to the relative folders in the com.mojang folder, but that doesn't seem to work either. This may be a bug which will need patching, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think behavior packs are available for android but not for IOS. I also saw a YouTuber called TrueTriz, he used them. The reason why is because IOS is more strict on that kinda stuff

Comment: Do you have more definitive proof of this?

Answer (score -2):

Go to minecraft garage. His site is incredible useful. I've successfully imported resource packs with his tutorials. You can't just place them in a folder anymore. They have to be opened and downloaded with mcpe running in the background on the iDevice to start, but you will need a computer to do the editing and formatting.

This is iOS - Mac way:

Go to computer: Go to mojang minecraft add-on page in web browser, there are two files at the bottom titled vanilla resource pack and Vanilla behavior pack. If you create a set of files with folders exactly as it appears in the vanilla packs, it will work. I haven't done a behavior pack yet, still working on getting a fully solid working resource pack. I am having issues with it loading, even though I have gotten mcpe app to accept it as a working resource.

Basically, download those, create a copy using your own textures/items etc. To read the .json files, you can open them in Text Edit, make sure when you edit that you are in Plain Text (in the format drop down menu). Go to minecraftgarage to the uid generator for the pack_manifest.json file-both id's have to be different, otherwise it won't port, can't copy the vanilla ones either, also, to make sure your .json files syntax is correct, he has a checker too. Use it. After you've done these steps, make a zip of the file you've created. Then, right click on zip file and select" Get Info".
In the box that has the name, change .zip to .mcpack, press enter. It will ask "are you sure you want to change to .mcpack?" select "Use .mcpack instead". Now you have an icon that looks like a piece of paper. Email that file to yourself, or, upload file to your file sharer of choice-I use dropbox (from mac browser, not the app). Then, go onto your iDevice, point your web browser to where you uploaded the .mcpack file, click it download. device will say there there isn't a program to look/read that file, then it will give you an option to "open in"... Make sure you have opened mcpe on the device and kept it open in the background. Choose "open in...mcpe, or "save to...mcpe". Device will switch over to mcpe app, and there will be a pop-up-drop down notification that your pack either did or didn't import. If it didn't work, then you know you need to go back and check for errors. It's tedious but work through every single file and image and .jsons.

Thats how to do it in a nutshell. Sorry if you've already received this but, I figure couldn't hurt. But truly, go to Minecraft Garage. People with macs and iOS folk are having a ton of issues, and we have some good discussion going on there.

I'm not spamming, I'm just answering someones question. There isn't a lot of information out about why iOS is having such a hard time with the new update. So excuse me for pointing out OTHER COMPLETELY VALID places to look. If you were 1 encyclopedia among an entire library of encyclopedias, would you honestly tell people *NOT* to continue their research in the quest for knowledge?

Comment: Lol thxs guys hope u enjoy 1.1 update